# Compiling Latex with Javascript

Tags: javascript, latex

I am working on a webapp(written with react-js) that generates a Latex code which contains information to give to the user. My goal is to **let the user download the PDF file directly from my application**.

I first tried using this library: [texlive.js](https://github.com/manuels/texlive.js/), that seemed to work but really it's impossible to recompile(**their "Makefile" is not meant to handle new packages**) if you try to add new packages(only some basic ones work).

So I thought about using the [overleaf APIs](https://www.overleaf.com/devs) but **they don't let you obtain the pdf without sending the user to their website**.

Any advice to make one of them work or any other way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently found this project:
https://github.com/SwiftLaTeX/SwiftLaTeX

I've tested it with a few documents and it seems to work. It downloads the needed packages from the web, see available packages: https://www.ctan.org/. I haven't gone deeper into passing images to the engine but it should be possible. See the official demo: https://www.swiftlatex.com/#demo

Here is the official guide with the download link for the already compiled wasm files and with the js bindings: https://www.swiftlatex.com/#install

Answer (score 1):

You can install your package in texlive.js without using MakeFile

Sorry I am not expert in answering but here is how i made it work

I wanted to implement exam paper generation using javascript

Required Package/Class : exam

I created **"\texlive.js\texlive\texmf-dist\tex\latex\exam\exam.cls"**

Added this to

**"\texlive.js\texlive\texmf-dist\ls-R"**

```
./tex/latex/exam:
exam.cls
```

And Then **\texlive.js\texlive.lst**

```
/texmf-dist/tex/latex/exam/.
```

And

```
/texmf-dist/tex/latex/exam/exam.cls
```